# Efficient random 0,1 generation of independant probabilities in Python

Tags: python, numpy, probability

I have a large array of probabilities that are independent of each other. Is there an efficient way to generate a 0 or 1 based on each of these probabilities other than calling numpy random each time in a loop? I only need the result of one trial each time, but for each of the probabilities.

```
# current method using np.random.binomial()
n = 1
p = np.random.random(1000) #generating 1000 probabilities

results = np.zeros(1000)
for ix, i in enumerate(p):
    results[ix] = np.random.binomial(n,i,1)
```

Is there a faster way or function that can take an independant set of probabilities (so not random choice, since the probabilities will not add to 1).

Comment: "_A large array of probabilities_" or a large array of samples? Please include a small slice of your array.

Comment: Definitely a large array of probabilities, in this case, I generated them randomly, but I will have from data a set of probabilities (values between 0 to 1) which I will use to get a sample.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `p` parameter to [`np.random.binomial`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.binomial.html) is allowed to be list-like, and when it is that way, it represents the `p` value for each sample. Also, when used list-like like this, you don't even need to provide the number of samples you expect in total: you just get one for each value in `p`.

```
results = np.random.binomial(n, p)
```

And some samples to prove this out:

```
In [1]: np.random.binomial(1, 0.5)
Out[1]: 1

In [2]: np.random.binomial(1, [0.5, 0.5, 0.9])
Out[2]: array([0, 0, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
np.where(p > np.random.rand(1000), 1, 0)
```