# How can I create an int variable?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-science, fillna

I wonderer how can I create an int variable that contains an huge amount of 0's and and big amount of 1's to do a Data Science models.

I know how crated a variable but not how to create a variable that contains lots of ints rapidly, I tried using fillna() to complete a variable, but I dont know how to add an especific amounts of an int to a variable on Python.

Comment: `return 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111`

Just kidding. Welcome to StackOverflow, you might want to be more descriptive for your question :)

Comment: You create a variable of type int by assigning an integer value (which may be the result of some expression or a constant) to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```py
# https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html
np.ones((5,), dtype=int)
>>> array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

# https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html
np.zeros(5)
>>> array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

or this? [Efficient random 0,1 generation of independant probabilities in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50222055/efficient-random-0-1-generation-of-independant-probabilities-in-python)

This is a very unspecific question and you might want to google first a little bit yourself...

Comment: Yes, and how can I create a variable an assign an amount of zeros an ones (to the same variable).

Comment: Your question makes no sense.. I may suggest making some Python tutorials to get the basics